# check to make sure first input digit is 0 using Entry property in Xamarin.forms

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms

I need to check the phone number which the user has entered, starts at 0 and has a minimum of 11 lengths. 
How can I do this?
Here is my code:

```
<Entry x:Name="txtPhoneNumber" Placeholder="شماره تلفن" Margin="5,10,10,5" FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
                   MaxLength="11"
                   Keyboard="Telephone">
                <Entry.Behaviors>
                    <local:NumericValidationBehavior/>
                    <local:MaxLengthValidatorBehavior  MaxLength="11"/>
                </Entry.Behaviors>
            </Entry>
```

Here is NumericValidationBehavior class:

```
public class NumericValidationBehavior : Behavior<Entry>
{
    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry entry)
    {
        entry.TextChanged += OnEntryTextChanged;
        base.OnAttachedTo(entry);
    }
    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry entry)
    {
        entry.TextChanged -= OnEntryTextChanged;
        base.OnDetachingFrom(entry);
    }
    private static void OnEntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(args.NewTextValue))
        {
            bool isValid = args.NewTextValue.ToCharArray().All(x => char.IsDigit(x)); //Make sure all characters are numbers

            ((Entry)sender).Text = isValid ? args.NewTextValue : args.NewTextValue.Remove(args.NewTextValue.Length - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the code in the behaviours implemented in

```
<local:NumericValidationBehavior/>
<local:MaxLengthValidatorBehavior  MaxLength="11"/>
```

If you share the code of these two behaviours, I can give you a more clear picture.

Kindly see the below code :-

private static void OnEntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
    {

```
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(args.NewTextValue))
    {
        bool isFirstNumberZero = args.NewTextValue.ElementAt(0) == '0';
        if(!isFirstNumberZero)
        {
            ((Entry)sender).Text = args.NewTextValue.Remove(args.NewTextValue.Length - 1);
            return;
        }

        bool isValid = args.NewTextValue.ToCharArray().All(x => char.IsDigit(x)); //Make sure all characters are numbers
        ((Entry)sender).Text = isValid ? args.NewTextValue : args.NewTextValue.Remove(args.NewTextValue.Length - 1);
    }
}
```

With this you can verify two things :-
1. First Number is 0.
2. All entered characters are digits.

Once the User taps on some button like Done/Submit/Login/Next.
That time you can verify the length of the entered number and then give an alert if the length is less than 11.